# Error while I'm trying to emulate project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error when I try to run on emulator:

> 03-24 11:42:49.843    1120-1120/com.mindrain.touchbreak E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mindrain.touchbreak/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
>               at com.mindrain.touchbreak.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:26)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And in my Manifest I have this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mindrain.touchbreak"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storage"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.set_orientation"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash2"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

In my Splash activity I have this:

```
package com.mindrain.touchbreak;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;


public class Splash extends Activity {


private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
private void openApp(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Splash2.class));
    finish();

}
}
```

In my Splash2 activity this:

```
package com.mindrain.touchbreak;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaActionSound;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;


public class Splash2 extends Activity {


private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_2);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash2.this,MainMenu.class);
            Splash2.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash2.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
private void openApp(){
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainMenu.class));
}
}
```

And in my MainMenu Activity this:

```
package com.mindrain.touchbreak;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainMenu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

public MediaPlayer mp = null;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:
            //startActivity(Game);
            break;
        case R.id.options:
            //startActivity();
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp == null) {
                //mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.menu);
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
        }

    });
}
}
```

Where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: when this error occurs?

Comment: prolly whe he is trying to use `startActivity` with wrong class .. please check classes passed to the intent twice and delete the question obviously he has somthing like `import android.view.Menu; .... startActivity(new Intent(context, Menu.class));`

Comment: Yes I want to know on which activity's start-up, this error comes.

Comment: poast your Splash activity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
```

to

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainMenu.class);
```

in Splash Activity.

Comment: Okay, this worked. Thanks. I have to watch over what I'm writting... xD